# Load multiple records into marklogic server

Tags: rest, marklogic

How can I upload multiple records in a file into marklogic server using RESTapi.
I tried to insert simple json format file

```
[{"Id":100000,"Name":"Dennis"},
{"Id":100001,"Name":"Andrea"},
{"Id":100002,"Name":"Robert"},
{"Id":100003,"Name":"Sara"}]
```

But, it gives me like one single record. 
How do I convert this into 4 different records?

Thanks in advance,
Y.Prithvi

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an out-of-the-box way to do that split at the moment. Your best bet is to do a client-side split and then [do a bulk-write POST with multiple JSON items to /v1/documents](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_54649)

For the client-side split, you might use something like [underscore_cli](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli) to do the splitting.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave points out, the easiest approach is to split out the documents on the client and send a multipart/mixed payload.

The alternative is to write a resource service extension to do the split. In MarkLogic 7, the service must be implemented in XQuery. In MarkLogic 8, you will also be able to implement a service in JavaScript.

The Java API bundles an example that illustrates the basic idea of a service that splits documents:

```
scripts/docsplit.xqy
com.marklogic.client.example.extension.DocumentSplitter
```